# How to set UninstallURL outside background.js / more than once?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need to update uninstall URL for my extension over its usage time.

However, looks like the `chrome.runtime.setUninstallURL` only works when invoked from `chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener({ ... if (details.reason == "install")`.

Where it doesn't work is in function which is a part of JS with `"run_at": "document_end"`: `if (chrome.runtime.setUninstallURL) ...` condition seems to be not met there.

Comment: As you can see [content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) can access only a very limited subset of API. Simply call setUninstallURL in an internal script of your extension such as the background script, no need to use a specific listener such as onInstalled.

Comment: @wOxxOm Worth making it an answer, helped me a lot.